# Can I, as a human, view the RSpec rendered views, and if, so how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would like to be able see the output from the path requested within one of my view specs. Rspec has access to the rendered view, but I would like access to it myself. Does anyone know how to actually view the rendered views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) with [launchy](http://rubygems.org/gems/launchy), and then you can use capybara's save_and_open_page method.  Read more details in this [blog post](http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/).

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to see it rendered in a browser or just HTML is fine? You should be able to access HTML in an instance variable called `@rendered`.

```
puts @rendered
# <html>...</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, you either don't want to use capybara + launchy, or you can't get it to work, you can just do this:

```
    IO.write('/tmp/test.html', rendered)
```

... and if you're on a mac:

```
    `open /tmp/test.html`
```