# How can I view the rendered page in an RSpec/Capybara view spec?

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I know in a normal feature spec using Capybara, I could do something like this:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "users/show", type: :feature do
  it 'renders a page' do
    visit user_path
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

Is there an equivalent way to view the rendered page in a view spec, without tagging it as a feature? Ie something like this:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "users/show", type: :view do
  it 'renders a page' do
    render
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

As is, I get a `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'save_and_open_page'` raised when I try this.

(I know I could just view the string as rendered, and [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36318308/3210927) someone suggested in a similar thread on feature specs works - and I could write my own method to do that if need be. But it seems likely there'd be some existing functionality for it?)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no existing functionality in view tests for opening the "page" in a browser.  By default only Capybaras matchers are included into view specs, not its session methods.  This is because view specs don't have a "browser", it's just your view templates being rendered and returned as a string (no CSS/JS loaded, no cookies, no real session, no interaction, etc).  As you pointed out it's easy enough to save the `rendered` string to a file and load into a browser if you actually need that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs it might be enough to simply create a `Capybara::Node::Simple` object from the `rendered` string in your view spec by following the approach shown in the article [validating views with capybara queries](https://www.thegnar.com/blog/validating-views-with-capybara-queries).

As taken from the article you can do:

```rb
it "does not render the account link when signed out" do
  ... # assign and render a view or template

  doc = Capybara.string(rendered)
  expect(doc).to have_no_css("nav a", text: "Account")
end
```

Note that this will allow you to use Capybara Finders methods (e.g. `#find`) on the doc element:

```rb
doc.find('p')
```

---

For more guidance on this topic have of a look at the card [RSpec: Leverage the power of Capybara Finders and Matchers for view specs](https://makandracards.com/makandra/611135-rspec-leverage-the-power-of-capybara-finders-and-matchers-for-view-specs)